# Problems with dropdown list in template field in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu, disabled-control

Okay so I have a gridview as the following html shows:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gridDetaljiNarudzbe" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10" runat="server" OnRowCommand="gridDetaljiNarudzbe_RowCommand" OnPageIndexChanging="gridDetaljiNarudzbe_PageIndexChanging" OnRowDataBound="gridDetaljiNarudzbe_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
           <asp:BoundField DataField="Naziv" HeaderText="Naziv" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="Sifra" HeaderText="Šifra" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="Cijena" HeaderText="Cijena" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="Kolicina" HeaderText="Količina" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Ocjena">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:TemplateField>
              <ItemTemplate> 
                  <asp:LinkButton ID="btnOcijeni" title="Ocijeni proizvod" CommandName="OcijeniCommand" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ProizvodID") %>' runat="server"><img src="../images/ocijeni.png" /></asp:LinkButton>
              </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

For filling out the dropdown list for each record in DB I have used the following code (RowDataBound event):

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                DropDownList drop = e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList1") as DropDownList;
                drop.Items.Add(new ListItem(""));
                drop.Items.Add(new ListItem("1"));
                drop.Items.Add(new ListItem("2"));
                drop.Items.Add(new ListItem("3"));
                drop.Items.Add(new ListItem("4"));
                drop.Items.Add(new ListItem("5"));
            }
```

For selecting a value from the dropdown list in each row:

```
   foreach (GridViewRow gr in gridDetaljiNarudzbe.Rows)
{
                        DropDownList drop = gr.FindControl("DropDownList1") as DropDownList;
                     // now selecting a value from dropdownlist 
                 int selectednumber = Convert.ToInt32(drop.Text);
}
```

Now my problem is, lets say we have two records in the grid, and I would like to pick up the value from the second dropdown list in 2nd row (lets suppose I did that). And when I press the button of the first record in first row, that  value which I have picked up from 2nd dropdown list is now inserted into the DB as if I selected something from the first drop list.

Also I would like to know if its possible after that something has been picked up in drop list and inserted into the DB, to disable now that dropdownlist and turn into static text which would show just 5 instead of the dropdownlist?

Can someone help me out with this please? I've tried everything but I haven't succeeded yet. :/

EDIT:

When I select something from the second grid(2nd dropdownlist as u can see the picture) and when I press the button to grade the first product, I get the grade from the 2nd dropdown list which I have selected. Is it any more clear now?

[image: Problem]

Thanks!

Edit here is the code for yogi:

```
   List<hsp_Proizvodi_SprijeciDvaPutaOcijeniti_Result> lista = ServisnaKlasa.SprijeciDvostrukoOcjenjivanje(ProizvodID, Sesija.kupac.KupacID);
                foreach (GridViewRow gr in gridDetaljiNarudzbe.Rows)
                {
                    if (lista.Count == 0)
                    {
                        DropDownList drop = gr.FindControl("DropDownList1") as DropDownList;
                        if (drop.SelectedIndex != 0)
                        {
                            Ocjene o = new Ocjene();
                            o.KupacID = Sesija.kupac.KupacID;
                            o.ProizvodID = ProizvodID;
                            o.Datum = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                            o.Ocjena = Convert.ToInt32(drop.Text);
                            ServisnaKlasa.OcjenjivanjeProizvoda(o);
                            string poruka = "Proizvod uspješno ocijenjen!";
                            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + poruka + "');", true);
                            drop.SelectedIndex = 0;

                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        string poruka = "Ovaj proizvod ste već ocijenili!";
                        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + poruka + "');", true);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: what is relation btwn first row drop down and second row down. you are not that much clear. what do you want and what is problem can you clarify it?

Comment: Can you see this picture: http://oi59.tinypic.com/2s0k4k9.jpg
When I select something from the second grid(2nd dropdownlist as u can see the picture) and when I press the button to grade the first product,  I get the grade from the 2nd dropdown list which I have selected. Is it any more clear now?

Comment: sorry i am not able to see this picture. can edit your question?

Comment: you are just saying what is happening not what you want! you want to stop getting grade from second drodown?

Comment: No thats not it, please see the picture on the updated question. P.S. I hope its more clear now

Comment: what i understand is if somebody didnt select anything in first dropdown and select 3 in second drop down and he clicks on first row's button,this second row '3' should be inserted with first row data. i am getting correct?

Comment: Yes yes thats exactly it, is there any way I can prevent this from happening?

Comment: can you show full code in which you are inserting values in db.?

Comment: I have added the code above, please refer to it. Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this approach

1. add gridview's `RowCommand` event.
2. Give a command argument for your link button.like this

   ```
   <asp:LinkButton ID="btnOcijeni" title="Ocijeni proizvod" CommandName="OcijeniCommand" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ProizvodID") + ";" +((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex%>' runat="server"><img src="../images/ocijeni.png" /></asp:LinkButton>
   ```

(i just added one more field in command argument for rowindex)

3. now where ever click on the link button the `RowCommand` event will be called.

   `protected void gridDetaljiNarudzbe_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
          {
               if (e.CommandName == "OcijeniCommand")
               {   arg = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(';');
                   int index = Convert.ToInt32(arg[1].ToString());
       //Finding same row dropdown list
       //This will give you same row dropdownlist not the below row
                   DropDownList drpdwn1= (DropDownList)gridDetaljiNarudzbe.Rows[index].FindControl("DropDownList1");

   //Now for BoundField  values
           GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];
           string NazivText= row.Cells[0].Text;//It will give Naziv's value
   //same way you can get other field values
   //And save into db.
              }
           }`

***Edit***

For converting the drop down to label

1. Add a label below your drop down list and make it `Visible=false`

   ```
    <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                   <asp:Label ID="lbl_ForDrpdwnVal" runat="server"  Visible="false"></asp:Label>
   ```
2. Now in the same item command event add the below code after inserting values to db.

   ```
                       //Access the new label
                       Label lblfordrpdwn= (Label)gridDetaljiNarudzbe.Rows[index].FindControl("lbl_ForDrpdwnVal");
                       lblfordrpdwn.Text= drpdwn1.SelectedItem.Text;//Setting value from dropdown to lbel
                       lblfordrpdwn.Visible=true;//Showing label
                       drpdwn1.Visible=false;//Hiding the dropdown
   ```

Comment: Dude ur the best, it works!!! Can you help me out with just one more thing? Now when something has been inserted into the DB( for a certain row), I would like to show a label in the grid showing the grade( 1,2,3,4,5) instead of the dropdown list for that certain row for which the grade has been inserted?

Comment: I am glad that it helps you. :)
you want to replace the dropdownlist with label after inserting value to database?

Comment: @perkes456 see the edit. hope it will solve your problem

Comment: Yes yogi thank you, I have another problem unfortunately :(. When 1 user rates 3 products lets say, and another user comes buys all 3 same products, and now when he tries to rate them, its not showing the dropdown list anymore,but just the label of grade itself (not the drop list for grading the products). Is there any way I can kick out the ratings from 1st guy for 2nd guy so that he can enter his own grades?

Comment: are you storing ratings for each user separately?

Comment: Yes, but the stored procedure I have is not good at all... Perhaps you could help me? I'm going to ask a new question about this, so I hope you'll be there to help :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65276/discussion-between-perkes456-and-yogi970).

Comment: Yogi It seems to work now , but I have another problem, can you come to chat please?

Comment: I have implemented it as you told me, and now when I grade the all 3 products with user 1, i log in with user 2 and start grading, it grades successfully with user 2, but it shows double columns now (it shows also user ratings from user 1)?? :/

Comment: @perkes456 again it is the same thing you are binding with all user data just bind with current user data only. add same where clause with current user session as you added in that query

Comment: Another problem now, when I add "and o.BuyerID=@BuyerID (from my session)" now it does shows grades buyers own grades, but if the buyer hasn't rated any product, now the grid isn't showing up at all ? :(